# Vertical asymptote of $h(x)=\frac{x^2e^x}x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$h(x)=\frac{x^2e^x}x$$

The function h is defined above. Which of the following are true about the graph of $y=h(x)$?

1. The graph has a vertical asymptote at $x=0$
2. The graph has a horizontal asymptote at $y=0$
3. The graph has a minimum point

> A. None
>
> B. 1 and 2 Only
>
> C. 1 and 3 Only
>
> D. 2 and 3 Only
>
> E. 1, 2, and 3

I thought it was E but the answer is D, meaning the vertical asymptote is not at $x=0$, why? If you set the denominator to $0$ it equals $0$ since $x=0$.

Comment: lookup hole :  http://www.purplemath.com/modules/grphrtnl4.htm

Comment: Hint: Try to simplify the function (assuming that $x\neq 0$)

Comment: I did use the method shown on the website, in which case the x would be equal to zero, which according to the answer for this question is wrong

Comment: This is the same as $xe^x$ with a removable singularity at $x=0$. The $x$ cancels, except when it equals zero so you can graph $y=xe^x$ except at zero.

Comment: @MohamedNouadir http://bit.ly/1t3HlBg If you look at a graph of the function, you can see that the minimum is at a negative $x$ and negative $y$. I'm not sure that the correct option is there.

Answer (score 3):

The denominator equaling zero is not enough to make a vertical asymptote. You get a vertical asymptote in the ratio of two continuous functions if the denominator is zero **and the numerator is not zero**.

In your particular case your function is the same as $xe^x$ near zero. The graph has a "hole" in it, also called a removable discontinuity.  You do not get an asymptote since a factor of $x$ cancels in numerator and denominator. In general, if both numerator and denominator are zero you may or may not get an asymptote.

Answer (score 0):

The function, as you've written it, appears to be the same as
$f(x) = x e^x$ (apart from right at zero)

You can easily see the behavior by plotting this function.

Plot this at www.fooplot.com/ using    $x \cdot 2.718^x$

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed negative values of $x$, then you do get a horizontal asymptote at $y = 0$ for negative $x$ because $x e^x$ increases up to $0$ (but never reaches it) as $x$ becomes larger and larger magnitude negative numbers. Also, if you are allowed negative $x$, then the function has a minimum. The derivative is $(x+1)e^x$ which is $0$ at $x = -1$ which is where the minimum is achieved. So if negative $x$ is allowed, then 2 and 3 are true.